# Can't run First Kaa App using java

Tags: java, windows-10, kaa

So I'm following " Your first Kaa application" tutorial using the Java SDK and everything goes smoothly up to the point of building the application. So when i try to run the application i get the following errors.

```
> C:\Temp\demo_app>dir  Volume in drive C has no label.  Volume Serial
> Number is F2BD-E432
> 
>  Directory of C:\Temp\demo_app
> 
> 09-Feb-17  06:34 PM    <DIR>          . 09-Feb-17  06:34 PM    <DIR>  
> .. 09-Feb-17  06:19 PM             1,030 FirstKaaDemo$1.class
> 09-Feb-17  06:19 PM             1,006 FirstKaaDemo$2.class 09-Feb-17 
> 06:19 PM             1,016 FirstKaaDemo$3.class 09-Feb-17  06:19 PM   
> 1,390 FirstKaaDemo$FirstKaaClientStateListener.class 09-Feb-17  06:19
> PM             4,314 FirstKaaDemo.class 09-Feb-17  05:48 PM           
> 5,814 FirstKaaDemo.java 09-Feb-17  06:00 PM        12,063,428
> kaa-java-ep-sdk-w1qr3q397vrCcqr1ErDhHwTpyWk.jar 09-Feb-17  06:12 PM   
> 10,905 slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar
>                8 File(s)     12,088,903 bytes
>                2 Dir(s)  98,984,988,672 bytes free
> 
> C:\Temp\demo_app>java -cp "..:..\*" FirstKaaDemo Error: Could not find
> or load main class FirstKaaDemo
> 
> C:\Temp\demo_app>java -cp "..;..\demo_app\*" demo_app.FirstKaaDemo
> Error: Could not find or load main class demo_app.FirstKaaDemo
```

Any clues about what might be going on ?

(There is a similar question but the answer does not work in my case. If by any chance i should just have asked this question on the foresaid post, please inform and i will remove my question.

After reinstalling java the problem vanished. I have no idea what caused this.

Comment: Who are you talking to?

Comment: Yes. sorry i edited the question. There is a similar question already answered (does not work for me) so at first i though i should only reply there but a friend of mine advised me to create a new post about this....
I'm Sorry for any confusion i might have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run it with:
`java -cp ".;.\*" FirstKaaDemo`.

See the [documentation](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/#launch-application%22documentation%22).

Comment: Yeap that did it.  Thanks a lot